# Conflict between different Jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have this jquery function:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").css("marginTop", $(window).scrollTop.length - offset.top);
                $("#sidebar").css({ opacity: 0.2 });

                $("#sidebar").mouseenter(function () {
                    $("#sidebar").css({ opacity: 1 })
                });
                $("#sidebar").mouseleave(function () {
                    $("#sidebar").css({ opacity: 0.2 })
                });
            } else {
                $("#sidebar").css("marginTop", "0");
                $("#sidebar").css({ opacity: 1 })
                $("#sidebar").mouseleave(function () {
                    $("#sidebar").css({ opacity: 1 })
                });
            };
        });
```

second function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#account-trigger').click(function () {
            $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
            if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
              $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
            else 
              $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
        })
        $('#cart-trigger').click(function () {
            $(this).next('#cart-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active'); if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
            else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
        });
 });
```

In the first function, i am trying to keep my #sidebar afloat at scroll,in the second function there is #sidebar which contains the menu that has the #account-trigger & #cart-trigger. #account-trigger & #cart-trigger opens up their sub menu respectively, on click.

The problem is when I click on the #account-trigger or #cart-trigger my window scroll automatically goes to top. There is no problem when the scroll is at top, indicating that  the first function is working fine.

How it should work is when i scroll the content the sidebar should come to the top and the opacity should decrease but on hover the sidebar opacity should reset to 1 and when clicked on the menu inside the sidebar, it should open menu there itself.

> **The answer is:** instead of putting # in href, when i put
>   javascript:void(0); it worked. thanx @mandeep it was pending from a
>   long time.

Comment: Can we see an example url?

Also, I suspect that #account-trigger and #cart-trigger are anchors with href="#".  Is that the case?  If so, just put return false; at the end of each click function.

Comment: Alternative to the @danwellman method you can also add href="javascript:void(0);" to the anchor tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of putting # in href, when i put javascript:void(0); it worked. thanx @mandeep it was pending from a long time.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the browser is following the links when they are clicked, you can disable this using the event object that is automatically passed to event handlers in jQuery, e.g:

```
$('#account-trigger').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault() // stops browser following links

    //continue
}
```